# linear extrapolation to $\infty$

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, extrapolation

In my "Numerical methods in Linear Algebra" course I have to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions/eigenvectors for the 1-D stationary Schrodinger equation. The interval where the $x$ axis is discretised is $[-a, a]$. As the number of gridpoints I have $N$, so the distance between two points $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ is $\Delta x = \frac{2a}{N}$. One of the tasks is to extrapolate the eigenfunctions to $\Delta x \to 0$ and $a \to \infty$.

I know that the difference between interpolation and extrapolation is that in the case of interpolation, the desired $x$ is in between the some given points $x_0$ and $x_{N-1}$, where we have $x_0 \lt x_1 \lt .... \lt x_{N-1}$ and extrapolation would be then the desired $x$ is outside the region of $x_0$ and $x_{N-1}$.

But I'm stuck with the extrapolation to infinity. Could somebody explain how to do this?

One example of an eigenfunction/eigenvector that i have is $[7.15552891e-09, \ 4.08699622e-06,\ 1.27412046e-03, \ 9.49478867e-02, \
 7.00702237e-01, \ 7.00701752e-01, \ 9.49477897e-02, \ 1.27409120e-03]$

Comment: I think you have to do it in two steps. First look at the limit of $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$ and try to find a closed form expression for the eigenfunction on a finite interval. Then see whether you can generalize to the entire real line,

Comment: No, there are precious few potentials for which a closed form solution of the eigenvalues and eigenvalue can be found. It is possible that OP will be able to do Richardson extrapolation for the eigenvalues and for value of the eigenvectors at individual points of the interval. In both cases, we treat the approximations as functions of the number N of subdivisions used and extrapolate to the case of $N =\infty$. We need to know if Richardson extrapolation is included in the course or not?

Comment: As a sample of what might be possible I refer to the following question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2780135/307944

Comment: @CarlChristian thanks for the reply!
We didn't use Richardson extrapolation in the course. 
If it helps, for this task the potential was $-\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4}$ and the eigenvalues and eigenvectors were calculated using the Jacobi eigenvalue algorithm

Comment: Let $c_n = \lambda_1^{(n)}$ denote the smallest eigenvalue when you have $n$ subintervals, i.e., $\Delta x = 2a/n$. In order to judge if Richardson extrapolation is possible, I need you to compute $c_{10}$, $c_{20}$, $c_{40}$, etc. Compute the fraction $f_n = \frac{c_n - c_{2n}}{c_{4n} - c_{2n}}$ for $n \in \{10,20,40,...\}$ It is very likely that $f_n \rightarrow 2^p$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  Here $p$ is an integer that hinges on how the equation was discretized. It is likely that you have $p=2$.